# How to run a new process and establish connection with it without any shell script?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

My purpose is create a new process of other program and establish with it  a long-time connection (opportunity to write to its stdin and read a result) i.e. not atomic write-read operation with following killing of created process. I have to use program code only, not any shell command.

There is my code:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['myprog', '-l'], shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
#proc was kept
#after some waiting I try to send to proc some command
if proc.returncode == None:
    proc.stdin.write(b'command')
    response = process.communicate()[0]
```

This code returns either empty string (if one transaction was commited) or rises BrokenPipeError (if it was running in loop). 
Does proc stay alive after the first `process.communicate()`? What approach I need to use to get control of stdin/stdout of proc?

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for `proc.returncode == None`.

But if you read the [documentation of subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode) the returncode is either `0` or a negative number, but never `None`.

- Second, if you have long running processes, you should either adjust and handle the `timeout`, or disable it..
- Third: You should really really really avoid `shell=True` in Popen, it is a huge security risk.

Here is some example how I normally deal with Popen:

```
from shlex import split as sh_split
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, TimeoutExpired


def launch(command, cwd=None, stdin=None, timeout=15):
    with Popen(
        sh_split(command), universal_newlines=True,
        cwd=cwd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE
    ) as proc:
        try:
            out, err = proc.communicate(input=stdin, timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutExpired:
            proc.kill()
            out, err = proc.communicate()
        return proc.returncode, out.splitlines(), err.splitlines()
```

This is for short living processes, but I hope you can see how stdin, stdout and stderr handling is done.